# How to convert List<String> to Map<String,List<String>> based on a delimeter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of String like:

```
List<String> locations = Arrays.asList("US:5423","US:6321","CA:1326","AU:5631");
```

And I want to convert in `Map<String, List<String>>` as like:

```
AU = [5631]
CA = [1326]
US = [5423, 6321]
```

I have tried this code and it works but in this case, I have to create a new class `GeoLocation.java`.

```
List<String> locations=Arrays.asList("US:5423", "US:6321", "CA:1326", "AU:5631");
Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations
        .stream()
        .map(s -> new GeoLocation(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]))
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(GeoLocation::getCountry,
                Collectors.mapping(GeoLocation::getLocation, Collectors.toList()))
        );

locationMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " = " + value));
```

**GeoLocation.java**

```
private class GeoLocation {
    private String country;
    private String location;

    public GeoLocation(String country, String location) {
        this.country = country;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

But I want to know, Is there any way to convert `List<String>` to `Map<String, List<String>>` without introducing new class.

Comment: Java's lack of tuples strikes again :(

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may do it like so:

```
Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split(":"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
                Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

A much more better approach would be,

```
private static final Pattern DELIMITER = Pattern.compile(":");

Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations.stream()
    .map(s -> DELIMITER.splitAsStream(s).toArray(String[]::new))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], 
            Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

**Update**

As per the following comment, this can be further simplified to,

```
Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations.stream().map(DELIMITER::split)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0], 
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: I don't see how the second approach is better. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. If you look at the source code of String.split you can see there's tons of optimization done for 1-char strings.

Comment: The latter outperforms the former since it uses a pre-compiled pattern.

Comment: `DELIMITER.splitAsStream(s).toArray(String[]::new)` why not just use `DELIMITER.split(s)`?

Comment: Strange result found when tried with 10 Million locations, pre-compiled pattern takes around 0.830 second and string split takes around the 0.58 second, much better approach is not the best approach from which you mentioned. So I using  `s -> s.split(":")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations.stream()
            .map(s ->  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>(s.split(":")[0], s.split(":")[1]))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: One can optimize the use of `split` twice there.

Comment: @Naman, right! just copied OP answer.`...map(s->s.split(":"))
                .map(s ->  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,String>(s[0],s[1]))...` although @Ravindra Ranwala is better

Answer (score 3):

You can just put the code in grouping by part where you put first group as key and second as value instead of mapping it first

```
Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations
            .stream()
            .map(s -> s.split(":"))
            .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( s -> s[0], Collectors.mapping( s-> s[1], Collectors.toList() ) ) );
```

Comment: I noticed it after posting it

Answer (score 2):

What about POJO. It looks not complicated comparing with streams.

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> groupByCountry(List<String> locations) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    locations.forEach(location -> {
        String[] parts = location.split(":");
        map.compute(parts[0], (country, codes) -> {
            codes = codes == null ? new HashSet<>() : codes;
            codes.add(parts[1]);
            return codes;
        });
    });

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your location map needs to be sorted based on keys, you can try the following

```
List<String> locations = Arrays.asList("US:5423", "US:6321", "CA:1326", "AU:5631");

    Map<String, List<String>> locationMap = locations.stream().map(str -> str.split(":"))
            .collect(() -> new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(), (map, parts) -> {
                if (map.get(parts[0]) == null) {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(parts[1]);
                    map.put(parts[0], list);
                } else {
                    map.get(parts[0]).add(parts[1]);
                }
            }, (map1, map2) -> {
                map1.putAll(map2);
            });

    System.out.println(locationMap); // this outputs {AU=[5631], CA=[1326], US=[5423, 6321]}
```

Comment: Sort doesn't matter in `Map`, The key and value should be present as like mentioned.