# Java 8 - How to read lines from file and store it to array conditionally

Tags: java, arrays

im working on a java program that read a file with multiple lines , these lines has structure like this :

```
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "X" DATAKEY      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         F DATA
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         F DATA
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         F DATA
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         GDATA      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         GDATA
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         GDATA       
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         G9    0000      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "Z" KEY2
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "X" DATAKEY       
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L 8888
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L 5678444
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L 7777
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L114100000      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L11410444      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L9    0000      
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "Z" KEY2
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "X" DATAKEY     
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L45543443
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L45543443
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L45543443
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L45543443    
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         L45543443           
datadatadatadatadatadatadatadata         "Z" KEY2
.........
```

this is my working java code to read all lines from this file :

```
Path inputFile;

inputFile = Paths.get("inputDir", "myfileName");

fileLines = Files.readAllLines(inputFile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

fileLines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

now my issue is , i want to read each block of line in a specific array dynamically (number of arrays equal number of block lines), a block of lines is constitued by line that contains "X" and ends with line contains "Z" , in my example i have tree blocks of lines , and i have to create 3 arrays each array should contains lines of each block.

can you please guide my on how i can achieve this using java 8 lambda methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write a method that parse/process a line and return an object. Then you can use it in a map operation (using `fileLines.stream().map(MyClass::myMethod)`)

Comment: For dynamic array in Java, use [Arraylist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: @NoDataFound Without a terminal operation, that will do nothing.

Comment: @Michael probably... but it is up to James to complete it, for example using collect, forEach, ...

Comment: When processing through streams you will have to set `.sequential()` as well. Don't know if it will always work correctly when the records are not processed in the same order as defined in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my Problem using the solution in this ticket :
[Java 8: How to convert List<String> to Map<String,List<String>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389575/java-8-how-to-convert-liststring-to-mapstring-liststring)

this is my final Code :

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map = fichierInialLines.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(line -> line.substring(0,29), 
                            Collectors.mapping(line -> line, Collectors.toList()))
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Some old school java code:

```
List<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<String>> records=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> tempRecord=null;
for(String fileLine:fileLines)
{
    if(fileLine.contains("\"X\""))
    {
        tempRecord=new ArrayList<>();
        tempRecord.add(fileLine); // add X line if necessary
    }
    else if (fileLine.contains("\"Y\""))
    {
        tempRecord.add(fileLine); // add Y line if necessary
        records.add(tempRecord);
        tempRecord=null;                
    } else {
        tempRecord.add(fileLine);
    }
}
// every entry in records contains a group of lines
```

Oops: noticed you asked for a lambda way. sorry

Comment: Hello @Conffusion , thank you for your response, in fact i found a new why to collect each block of lines since each block has a unique identifier so collected all lines in Map of Lists  : Map<String, List<String>>